# Check: Oracle Data Access Components for Windows 7

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle9i

i have downloaded ODAC92070.exe from the Oracle Site [x32bit].  i need to install it on Windows 7 x32 bit. on installation instruction: System Requirements
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/install9207-086815.html
 its doesnt seems it would work on Windows 7 x32 or Windows 2008 r2 x32. Can i able to run and install  Oracle Universal Installer (OUI) on windows 7 x32bit?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Universal Installer is a Java application that can handle complex requirements. ODAC release for 9.2.0.7.0 will work fine with Windows7 32 bit release. If you face any problem during installation change the compatibility setting to "WindowsXP ServicePack 2".
Hope it helps.